# Java output in probability counting

Tags: java, probability

I have encountered a problem considering the difference between the mathematical output and the one the program gives.

I want to count the probability of gaining the same number twice in 1/6 probability, which should be `1 in 1/6 * 1/6 = 36`. However, I get an answer between 1 in 42-43. What is wrong?

```
int guess = (int) (Math.random() * 6);
int real = (int) (Math.random() * 6);
int countTot = 0;
int countReal = 0;
int countGen = 0;

while (true) {
    if (countReal == 2) {
        countGen++;
        countReal = 0;
        if (countGen == 1000000) {
            System.out.println("Probability: 1 in " + countTot/countGen);
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
    if (guess == real) {
        countReal++;
        countTot++;
    } else {
        countReal = 0;
        countTot++;
    }
    guess = (int) (Math.random() * 6);
    real = (int) (Math.random() * 6);
}
```

Consider that I do this `1000000` times (`countGen`) and take the average of the results. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running the following code:

```
int n = 1_000_000;
int count = 0;
Random rnd = new Random();

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    int a = rnd.nextInt(6);
    int b = rnd.nextInt(6);
    int c = rnd.nextInt(6);
    int d = rnd.nextInt(6);

    if (a == b && c == d) {
        count++;
    }
}

System.out.println(count + " / " + n);
System.out.println("Or about 1 in " + (n * 1.0 / count));
```

Gives

> 27893 / 1000000
>   Or about 1 in 35.8512888538343

So, why do you get 1 in 42?

Consider, if you get 2 numbers the same, you increment `countReal`.  If you get 2 numbers the same a second time, you increment `countReal` again (and then reset it to zero).  If you get 2 numbers the same ***again***, you've already aborted counting your run.  This <s>probably</s> affects your probability.

---

Shown another way:

```
int n = 1_000_000;
int count = 0;
Random rnd = new Random();

boolean matched_last_time = false;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    int a = rnd.nextInt(6);
    int b = rnd.nextInt(6);
    boolean match = a == b;

    if (match && matched_last_time) {
        count++;
        // match = false;  // Uncomment this line, & probability changes to 1 in 42
    }
    matched_last_time = match;
}

System.out.println(count + " / " + n);
System.out.println("Or about 1 in " + (n * 1.0 / count));
```

Comment: And this algorithm is much more clear than OP's as well.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I understand now!

Answer (score 2):

You're counting the number of consecutive matching pairs without allowing overlap. If you get a sequence of 3 random numbers that are all equal you should count 2 pairs, but you only count one. Not permitting overlap means that one pair depends on what came before it. To be able to multiply probabilities you have to guarantee that the events are independent.

Answer (score 1):

You are counting it wrong. You are comparing number of throws (countTot) to number of successful **double comparisons**. What you should get it 1/72. But you are not getting it, because if early exit if first pair is not matching.

Code below gives correct answer. It is not really nice, I would rename most of things, but I wanted to keep it as similar to original as possible

```
int guess = (int) (Math.random() * 6);
    int real = (int) (Math.random() * 6);
    int countTot = 0;
    int countReal = 0;
    int countGen = 0;

    while (true) {
        if (countReal == 2) {
            countGen++;
            countReal = 0;
            if (countGen == 1000000) {
                System.out.println("Probability: 1 in " + (countTot/2)/countGen);
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
        if (guess == real) {
            countReal++;
            countTot++;
        } else {
            countTot++;
            if ( countReal == 0 ) {
                countTot++;
            }
            countReal = 0;
        }
        guess = (int) (Math.random() * 6);
        real = (int) (Math.random() * 6);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I understand now!